# How can I override a Collection.php file from a 3rd party plugin?

Tags: overrides, magento2.4

I have 2 plugins that are clashing with each other. I figured out a fix, and I have to change a collection.php file, and I don't want it to get overwritten in a future plugin update. How can I get this done?

Thanks

Comment: Provide  more details on clashing

Comment: Search dropdown isn't working form Mirasvit search because Mageplaza Layered Navigation is causing trouble. I had the Mirasvit people change something in the collection.php of Mageplaza, but I don't want the files to get overwritten